# How can I print results properly in Notepad using webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to print the results in proper format. Can anyone help?

```
 WebElement table=wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='grdFind']/tbody"));
        List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        System.out.println("total Rows :"+rows.size());
        System.out.println("Table has following content");
        for(int i=1; i<rows.size(); i++)
        {
            List<WebElement> cells=rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));

              for(int j=0; j<cells.size(); j++)
              {
                  String x=cells.get(j).getText();

                  BW.write(x); 
                  BW.write("  |  ");
                  }
                  BW.newLine();
         }
        BW.close();
```

Comment: What do you mean by proper format? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: First few columns data showing in a order after that remaining columns are not in order, i am expecting that data need to be show in proper order in column wise.  hope u can understand for reference plz find my attachment link     http://i.stack.imgur.com/okf7D.png

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is by using Charactor count.

Select the data with highest char length in column 3. Let's call it as x.
y is the data you are printing currently.

Your forumla should be:

```
x - y % 5 = z
```

and you have to print "\t" z times.

Here,

```
x is selected data length.
y is printing data length.
z is result of formula.
% is modulus operator
```

Comment: i am getting this error while using your formula  x - y % 5= z;  "The operator % is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int" and i am new to selenium so can you please elobarate

Comment: I guess you are using Java. And you're not supposed to copy as it is mentoned here. I have just given you the way to do it.

Comment: In Java % is modulus operator.